# What does enableProof do in passportjs OAuth 2.0? Does it enable pkce?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-google-oauth

I want to implement oAuth2.0 but after reading about oAuth 2.0 it is my understanding that it should use  Authorization Code grant-type and should also use PKCE. I am using passportJs to implement oAuth2.0 but at the same time, I don't want any kind of security issues of security holes. I know that passportJs uses the default Authorization Code grant flow. but I also want to implement PKCE with it. Passport mentions in their documentation `enableProof: true`. Does this enable PKCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enableProof has nothing to do with PKCE. PKCE is a security measure used *while* performing the oAuth authentication. The oAuth authentication results in an access token. You use that access token to perform API requests. EnableProof turns on appsecret_proof which is another security measure, to use *after* you get your access token, to make it impossible for someone to make API calls on your behalf with only the access token. The appsecret_proof parameter is added to each API call when enableProof is set to True.

Since access tokens are portable, it's possible to steal the token from a client and make calls on behalf of that client. An access token can also be stolen by malicious software on a person's computer or a man in the middle attack.

You can prevent this by adding the appsecret_proof parameter to every API call from a server and enabling the setting to require proof on all calls. The app secret proof is a sha256 hash of your access token, using the app secret as the key. All this is handled by PassportJs if you set enableProof to true.

PassportJs native oauth2 package also [supports pkce](https://medium.com/passportjs/pkce-support-for-oauth-2-0-e3a77013b278) with the option `pkce` set to True. If you use the passport-facebook package, which depends on the native package you can use that setting too. So just add this to you configuration:

```
state: true,
pkce: true
```

And you should be golden. You can even add `enableProof: true` for extra security after authentication.

Comment: I am using facebook oAuth2.0 I have a query that enablingProof is the same as  PKCE: true or not? as pkce secures the exchange of code. do enablingProof do the same job...?

Comment: enableProof has nothing to do with PKCE. PKCE is a security measure used while performing the oAuth authentication. The oAuth authentication results in an access token. You use that access token to perform API requests.
EnableProof turns on appsecret_proof which is another security measure, to use *after* you get your access token, to make impossible for someone to make API calls on your behalf with only the access token. TL;DR PKCE is for security during the authentication, enableProof is for security after authentication.

Comment: @KunalGupta I've added some explanation on how to turn on PKCE for the oAuth flow. Read https://medium.com/passportjs/pkce-support-for-oauth-2-0-e3a77013b278 for more useful info.